# What does "Received a NULL pointer" mean by?

Tags: gdal

I attempted to execute gdal_array.SaveArray, while the error prompted as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Python34/Mycase/gdalarray_use.py", line 5, in

```
gdal_array.SaveArray(band1,"D:/PyGDAL_Case/dem_cjz.tif",format="GTiff")
```

File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 240, in SaveArray

```
return driver.CreateCopy( filename, OpenArray(src_array,prototype) )
```

File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1478, in CreateCopy

```
return _gdal.Driver_CreateCopy(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.

The issue seems to be related to _gdal.Driver_CreateCopy,right? And I don't konw what is the meaning of "Received a Null pointer".
What measures should I take to tackle this problem?

Comment: I came across the same problem.. did you get this solved?